# WooCommerce v2 - echo order quantity

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am manipulating a table that shows orders.

I have managed to show some data from this using the below example (getting their phone number)

```
$order = new WC_Order( $item['order_id'] );
$phone = $order->billing_phone;
```

I have tried $order->quantity but that returns nothing - so not sure what variable I need to use.

Can someone assist?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get WooCommerce order details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39401393/how-to-get-woocommerce-order-details)

Comment: Check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54827027/1117368)